# Mathjax dropdown list print to preview- Nothing happens onchange

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

```
   {
    id: 'test',
    type: 'html',
    html:
        '<html>' +
        '<head>'+
        '<script type="text/javascript">'+       
        'function jsFunction(value){'+
        'this._.dialog.setValueOf("info","equation",value+"something");'+
        'preview.setValue("something"+value),'+
        '}'+
        '</script>'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '<p>Hello world!</p>'+
        '<select onchange="jsFunction(value)">'+
        '<option value="something">something</option>'+
        '<option value="something2">something2</option>'+
        '</select>'+
        '</body>' +
        '</html>'               
},
```

All I get is a dropdownlist with 2 options and nothing happens onchange. Any clues? I want it to work with preview onchange.

Comment: **nothing happens onchange**. Add `onchange` code in question...

Answer (score 0):

.onclick should be set to a function instead of a string inline. Try

```
 {
id: 'test',
type: 'html',
html:
    '<html>' +
    '<head>'+
    '<script type="text/javascript">'+ 
    'var el = document.getElementById("p1")'+
    'if (el.addEventListener) {'+
    'el.addEventListener("onchange", yourFunction, false);'+
    ' } else {'+
    ' el.attachEvent("onchange", jsFunction(this));'+
    '}'+
    'function jsFunction(value){'+
    'this._.dialog.setValueOf("info","equation",value+"something");'+
    'preview.setValue("something"+value),'+
    '}'+
    '</script>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<p>Hello world!</p>'+
    '<select id="p1">'+
    '<option value="something">something</option>'+
    '<option value="something2">something2</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '</body>' +
    '</html>'               
},
```

Comment: you are missing a + after '}' but even with this, nothing happens.
May i ask what are p1 and yourFunction? still keep changing values and no preview, no text in textarea. Oh by the way that was on change not onclick

Comment: I have changed the event to onchange. After changing did this worked?

Comment: No i tried this myself , too ... i m not sure if there is actually an onchange attachEvent